# Tslint - ignore files containing string: "spec"?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, tslint

I need to ignore all files containing spec int their name for example MyStuff.spec.ts

How can I make tslint to ignore this type of files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in tsconfig json add:

```
  "exclude":[
    "node_modules",
    "**/__test*", //exclude all that *__test*
    "**/*.spec.ts" // exclude all that contain "spec.ts" in name
  ]
```